# Using for and array_flip to simulate multiple foreach. Is there a better way?

Tags: php, foreach, array-flip

Is there a better way to do something like this? This is fine but I'd think there's probably a shortcut to get the same results. I guess to add more arrays easily I could just turn it into a function and have the for loop outside it but still.

Just wondering.

```
<?
$array1 = array("test1","test2","test3","test4");
$array2 = array("dest1","test2","dest3","dest4");




    for ($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++) { //FOR STATEMENT TO GET MULTIPLE ARRAYS REGISTERED AS A FOREACH-STYLE 
    $val1 = $array1[$i]; //VALUES GET
    $val2 = $array2[$i];

    $array1 = array_flip($array1); //ARRAY IS FLIPPED FROM KEY => VALUE TO VALUE => KEY SO THAT THE KEYS CAN BE GET. REMEMBER TO SWITCH IT BACK.
    $array2 = array_flip($array2);

    $key1 = $array1[$val1]; //NOW MUST ITERATE THROUGH USING VALUES ABOVE BECAUSE THE KEYS ARE NO LONGER NUMBERS.
    $key2 = $array2[$val2];

    $array1 = array_flip($array1); //SWITCHING IT BACK.
    $array2 = array_flip($array2);

    echo $key1 . "=>" . $val1 . "<br />";
    echo $key2 . "=>" . $val2 . "<br />";

    }




    var_dump($array1);

    ?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The keys for the arrays are just `$i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the "keys" for the arrays, `$i`.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++) {
    $val1 = $array1[$i]; // You're getting the value from the array,
    $val2 = $array2[$i]; // you already have the key, $i

    echo $i . "=>" . $val1 . "<br />";
    echo $i . "=>" . $val2 . "<br />";
}
```

EDIT: If both arrays have the same keys, you can `foreach` over one, and get the value from the other.

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>$val1){
    $val2 = $array2[$key];

    echo $key . "=>" . $val1 . "<br />";
    echo $key . "=>" . $val2 . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Oh right....well actually I'm trying to use this with arrays that don't have numbers as keys. Like (ID => Person) type stuff...I completely forgot that numbers won't work because of that so I'll have to make it a next() and current() instead of going by $i.

Comment: @user1159454: Do both arrays have the same keys?  If so, try the 2nd example I added.

Answer (score 1):

The best i can make for the moment

```
$arrayList = Array($array1, $array2); // Add every array here
$keyArr = Array();
foreach ($arrayList as $key => $value)
{
   // Put the keys of every array in $arrayList in an other array
   $keyArr[$key] = array_keys($value);
}
// Loop while $i is lower than the highest index of the bigest array in $arrayList
for ($i = 0; $i < count(max($arrayList )); $i++)
{
   // Loop every array in $arrayList
   foreach ($arrayList as $arrKey => $arr)
   {
     // If the array in $arrayList has at least $i element
     if ($i < count($arr))
     {

       // Get the key of the $i-n element in the array (take it from the $keyArr defined above)
       $key = $keyArr[$arrKey][$i];
       // Get the value of the $i-n element in the array
       $val = $arr[$key];
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated.

Comment: I edited it, it's the only way i found to "foreach" a lot of array at one time without manipulating keys and without looping each array.